# Any MergeCursor sample for android?

Tags: android, join, cursor

I want to join the results of multiple cursors and I found that the SDK provides the MergeCursor class but I am not sure how to use it. Does anyone know where to find a sample code please?

To be more precise I want a sample for sorting a MergeCursor...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look at [MergeCursorTest](http://source.android.com/compatibility/downloads.html) in the Compatibility Test Suite (CTS). It gives you a good overview how to use it.